# The values are sorted incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift

I list the 3 most common words in a Textview. Then I translated these words via Google Translate to use a framework. I want to do that to show the translation of these words I have listed with a different UILabel. 
But I have a problem. When I do this in Translate function, the translated words are sorted incorrectly.

How can I solve this problem?

Screenshot and codes as are below.

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtMain: UITextView!
    var commonWordsArray = [String]()
    var yPoint = 250

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        findCommonWords()
        translate()
    }

    func findCommonWords() {
        let textViewText = txtMain.text

        //separate the text into words and get rid of the "" results
        let commonWords = textViewText?.lowercased().components(separatedBy: [" ","."]).filter({ !$0.isEmpty })

        //count the occurrence of each word
        let wordCounts = NSCountedSet(array: commonWords!)

        //sort the words by their counts in a descending order, then take the first three elements
        let sortedWords = wordCounts.allObjects.sorted(by: {wordCounts.count(for: $0) > wordCounts.count(for: $1) }) [0..<3]

        for word in sortedWords {
            print("\(word) \(wordCounts.count(for: word)) times")

            let myLabel = UILabel()
            myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 25)
            myLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 80, y: yPoint)
            myLabel.text = word as? String
            myLabel.textAlignment = .left
            self.view.addSubview(myLabel)

            yPoint += 30

            commonWordsArray.append(word as! String)
        }

        yPoint = 250

        print(commonWordsArray)
    }

    func translate() {
        let translator = ROGoogleTranslate()
        translator.apiKey = "YOURAPIKEY" // Add your API Key here

        var params = ROGoogleTranslateParams()
        params.source =  "tr"
        params.target =  "en"

        for i in commonWordsArray {
            params.text = i

            print(i)

            translator.translate(params: params) { (result) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let myLabel = UILabel()
                    myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 25)
                    myLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 250, y: self.yPoint)
                    myLabel.text = result
                    myLabel.textAlignment = .left
                    self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
                    print(result)
                    self.yPoint += 30
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because these words sort by common word count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this part of the code is the source of your trouble:

```
   for i in commonWordsArray {
        params.text = i

        print(i)

        // for each word you call translate asynchronously
        translator.translate(params: params) { (result) in
            // and here you add the word to the UI on the main thread
            // however, this callback does not have to be called in the same order in which you called translate, 
            // and thus you can end up with different orders

            // add this line to confirm my hypothesis (if it prints correct pairs of words, then I am right):
            print(">>>> \(i) is \(result)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let myLabel = UILabel()
                myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 25)
                myLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 250, y: self.yPoint)
                myLabel.text = result
                myLabel.textAlignment = .left
                self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
                print(result)
                self.yPoint += 30

            }
        }
    }
```

The callback of the `translate` method gets called in undefined order - based on when the remote call returns. Synchronizing it on the main thread won't help with the order, because it will be already in wrong order.

If I am right, you have to find a way how to put those pairs together. I would for example prepare the labels for translation along with the labels for original words, and only fill their text in the callback from translate - `i` and `result` are paired correctly in the callback, use that fact (for example you can use dictionary to store translation label for each word, and then retrieve it in callback).

**EDIT: A possible solution**

One of many ways how to achieve what you want (replace your for loop with the following):

```
for i in commonWordsArray {
    params.text = i

    let myLabel = UILabel()
    myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 25)
    myLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 250, y: self.yPoint)
    myLabel.textAlignment = .left
    self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
    self.yPoint += 30

    translator.translate(params: params) { (result) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            myLabel.text = result
        }
    }
}
```

In this code you will create and add a label for each `i` in correct order (since you are doing it before calling the asynchronous `translate` method. Since the closure you pass to the `translate` call captures the local variables in its scope, in the callback the `myLabel` variable will point to the correct label for the given result, regardless of the order in which the callbacks will be executed.

Comment: >>>> güzel is beautiful
beautiful
>>>> kuş is bird
bird
>>>> gördüm is I saw
I saw  results are these when I added your line. Probably you'r right. But how can I solve this problem. For example: If I create an array and add result to this array and sort this created array. Is it solution?

Comment: that's the correct pairing, right? so the translate works correctly, the problem is in in what order you are adding those words to the UI

Comment: well, you cannot rely on the order in which they come. so you have to come with a different strategy to put the to the right labels.. I can give you one possible solution, I'll edit the answer

Comment: that's a great idea! It works. How couldn't I think this way :). Thank you very very much.